# websphere system error logging doesn't contain stacktrace

Tags: hibernate, jpa, logging, websphere

Have system error log which **doesn't contain stacktrace**.

```
[19.06.15 18:21:11:887 MSK] 00000381 InjectionBind E   CWNEN0030E: В фабрике @PersistenceUnit возникла ошибка при получении объекта привязки primary для экземпляра объекта.  Сообщение об исключительной ситуации: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
[19.06.15 18:21:11:887 MSK] 00000381 ResourceInjec E   CWOWB0102E: Ошибка JCDI: Unable to obtain an instance for primary: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
[19.06.15 18:21:11:887 MSK] 00000381 ResourceInjec E   CWOWB0102E: Ошибка JCDI: Unable to obtain an instance for primary: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: primary] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

Non-system errors are logging fine. How can I fix it?
Using WAS 8.5.5, JDK1.7, JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.2.5.
Watch logs with eclipse console.

log4j.properties:

```
#Default log level to ERROR. Other levels are INFO and DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE, CONSOLE

#CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p [%t.%F] - %m%n

#FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/moch.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1000KB
#Keep 5 old files around.
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#Format almost same as WebSphere's common log format.
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %t %c %-5p - %m%n

#Optionally override log level of individual packages or classes
log4j.logger.ru.my=TRACE
log4j.logger.ru.my.snuil.moch=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is printed by WebSphere Application Server itself, so your log4j settings are not relevant.  The error message seems like a usability issue, so you should problem open a PMR with IBM, but you could try using the trace settings from the [must gather for CDI problems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21595319) to see if that gives you any hints.  If not, you'll probably need to get help from IBM.

Answer (score 0):

WAS uses `Java Util Logging` for internal logging so your `log4j` configuration does not apply here. You can enable detailed trace logging and possibly get more information regarding the problem — see [Setting up a trace in WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254706).